# Store user date and time picker as a date

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetimepicker

I am new to Android Studio and am trying to store the user selections from a date and time picker as a Date in order to subtract 2 dates from each other using Joda Time. I have created a variable called 'timeselected' which will include all of the users selection, however at the minute it is stored as a string and I need it to be changed to a Date datatype. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

The code is:

```
String Stimeselected = ""+(yearNow) + (monthNow) + (dayNow) + (hourNow) + (minuteNow);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android Developers Date reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html):

> ```
> Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec)
> ```
>
> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>
> ```
> Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).
> ```

Or specifically for [Joda DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):

> ```
> DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour)
> ```

Comment: I already have the variables 'yearNow, monthNow' etc in use i just want to bring them together into one variable called 'timeselected' as a date

Comment: If I understand you correctly: would creating a Date or DateTime instance not be what you want? `Date date = new Date(yearNow, monthNow, dayNow, hourNow, minuteNow);`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you good you need to convert selected time and day to date format so use simpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

and instead of saving it like `String Stimeselected = ""+(yearNow) + (monthNow) + (dayNow) + (hourNow) + (minuteNow);` use `String Stimeselected = day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year+ " " + hour + ":" + minute ;`
finally parse the string `Date date = formatter.parse(Stimeselected )`